# MapView's source code

Tags: android, google-maps, android-mapview

Where can I get the source code of the MapView class from the Google Maps for Android package? I have only managed to find something that inherits from MockView and that's not what I'm looking for. I need the original MapView. Thanks.

Comment: in pursuance of google policies you cant get it.

Comment: Ok thanks, can you please write your response as an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It stinks, but it appears that Google hasn't released the source code yet - probably because they don't want unwanted users spamming their Maps service.  The Google API's are not provided in the SDK platforms; they have to be downloaded separately in the SDK Manager.  I had a similar problem when working with the Speech Recognition API.  I also found [this](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/1.5_r4/com/google/android/maps/MapView.java) source code, but it appears to be the `MockView` that you were talking about.

Answer (score 0):

I think <strike>I found it on gitorious, see it [**here**](http://gitorious.org/android-maps-api/android-maps-api/blobs/master/src/com/google/android/maps/MapView.java#line47)</strike> .

Comment: unfortunally its only a clone of that API, see the description: Open source clone of Google’s Android Maps API, using Open Street Maps and other map sources